# Color variable changing for every mapped item tailwind react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tailwind-css

I want that once i add another item in the list the color for the previous item should not be changed

```
const NoteItem = ({ note }) => {
  const { colors, randomColorFunction } = useContext(AppContext);
  const color = randomColorFunction(colors);
  return (
    <div
      className={`flex flex-col min-h-28  py-6 justify-between px-3 rounded-md whitespace-pre-wrap break-words`}
      style={{ backgroundColor: `${color}` }}
    >
      <span className="font-bold text-3xl">{note.title}</span>
      <span>{note.content}</span>
      <small className="text=xl">{note.date}</small>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You could solve this 2 ways

##### 1. useRef

```js
import { useRef } from "react";

const NoteItem = ({ note }) => {
  const { colors, randomColorFunction } = useContext(AppContext);
  const color = useRef(randomColorFunction(colors));

  return (
    <div
      className={`flex flex-col min-h-28  py-6 justify-between px-3 rounded-md whitespace-pre-wrap break-words`}
      style={{ backgroundColor: `${color.current}` }}
    >
      ...
    </div>
  );
};
```

##### 2. useState

```js
import { useState } from "react";

const NoteItem = ({ note }) => {
  const { colors, randomColorFunction } = useContext(AppContext);
  const [color] = useState(randomColorFunction(colors));

  return (
    <div
      className={`flex flex-col min-h-28  py-6 justify-between px-3 rounded-md whitespace-pre-wrap break-words`}
      style={{ backgroundColor: `${color}` }}
    >
      ...
    </div>
  );
};
```

If you're not looking to change the color I think `useRef` is more appropriate.

See here [a live preview](https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-engelbart-o8vj5s)